# Flutter TextField fill and border colors doesn't change to grey

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to style `TextField` according to design, but when I try to set fill and border color they are not changed:

```
child: Container(
                    height: 30,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: runSearch,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Color(GoEngColors.mainColorActive)),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                const Radius.circular(30.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                            filled: true,
                            focusedBorder: null,
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Color(GoEngColors.primaryTextColor)),
                            hintText: "Поиск",
                            fillColor: Color(GoEngColors.munsell)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Actual result [image]

Expected result [image]

```
static int munsell = 0xFF0F0F0;
```

How to set this colour as a background and remove borders?

**UPDATE**

With the help of the suggested solutions, I could get success in a normal state

[image]

But here's a result in the selected(focused) state:

[image]

How can I remove underline and remain hint and text on the same level?

Answer (score 3):

It seems your color code is wrong. You forgot to add one more `F`

```
int munsell = 0xFFF0F0F0;
```

And you have to set enabled border style as well for your `InputDecoration`

```
enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0.0),
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(30.0)),
                )
```

Comment: thank you very much! It helped, but can you take a look on my update?

Comment: @IgorSkryl In your updated question, it seems you're using `UnderlineInputBorder` instead of `OutlineInputBorder`. So just change the border type.

Comment: As you can see my post I use `OutlineInputBorder`, not `UnderlineInputBorder`

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: AppThemeData.darkColor,
                      hintText: 'Email'),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I stopped using the TextField widget in favor of the CupertinoTextField widget. This is because changing its properties was much more straight forward. I've forgotten how to do this in TextField but in Cupertino you'd just make these declarations like you would a container with a BoxDecoration. You could give that a try.

Comment: I use Material widgets

Comment: ....so? You're not stuck with using one widget over the other... You can mix and match....

Comment: Wow! I didn't know I can! Will try it out! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below sample

```
new Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: 60.0,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              border: new Border.all(
                color: Colors.black54,
                width: 4.0
              ),
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(12.0)
            ),
            child: new TextFormField(
              decoration: null,
            ),
          )
```

[image: Output]

You can remove the borders and it will match your requirement.